# How to VideoBrush in c# windows form application?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to get webcam video through VideoBrush but the issue is I can't show it on my form as picture box doesn't have fill property. I have tried other containers too but none worked. Help please??

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't use VideoBrush with a WinForms control, but I might very well be wrong. But VideoBrush seems like a WPF/Silverlight control.

Comment: Your tagging is confusing, Silverlight has nothing to do with WinForms, do you mean WinForms application, or WPF application or even out of browser Silverlight application?

Answer (score 1):

VideoBrush is WPF/Silverlight. If you want to host it in a Windows Forms application you need to put an element with the VideoBrush inside an [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Comment: That's helpful. Please write down the code how actually i can accomplish this?